# How to filter url in Apache configuration

Tags: apache, webserver

We have an Apache web server that receive user requests. It only allows https connections `JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS`. But now we have a new requirement, which will allow a particular url pattern like `/myurl` on http via Apache. That is, we want Apache to only accept http if a particular url pattern is thrown at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Location block to restrict/allow access

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but you could block the root location:

```
<Location />
   Deny from all
</Location>
```

And then add a location to allow

```
<Location /myurl>
   Allow from all
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion did not work for me with Apache 2.2.15. I had to do something different although still along the lines suggested above:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Location / >
    Require all denied
  </Location>
  <Location /my-dir>
    Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```